# chartjs - don't show all x-axis data points, but show all in tooltips

Tags: chart.js

I'm using a chartjs line chart with 2 lines. I have 7 x-axis data points. I only want to show the first, second, and last data point. BUT I want to show each datapoint in the tool tip. for now, I'm only listing 1, 2 and 7 in the x-axis label, so the tooltip shows correctly on the 2, but in other areas of course there's nothing. So is there a way to NOT show specific datapoints on the x-axis (but still have that data in the code to be used for the tooltip)?  (also, this is a very simplified example of what I'm trying to do)

```html
labels: ['1', '2', '','', ,, '7'],
```

thanks.

[image]

Comment: Do I understand your correctly that you want to show all labels at the tooltip but only 1., 2. & last label at the x-axis?

Comment: I would like to add the xAxis data in the tooltip, all across the lines. Currently, no xAxis data is shown in tooltip, because I only have data in the 1,2, and 7th area. My objective is to not crowd the xAxis, BUT to show the xAxis numbers in the lines with the tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should label your data correctly from 1 to 7 and filter the xAxis labels in the callback function.

```
scales: {
  xAxes: [{
    ticks: {
      beginAtZero: true,
      callback: function(value, index, values) {
        if (index === 0 || index === 1 || index === count - 1) { // count = yourNumberOfDataValues
          return value
        }
      }
    },
    gridLines: {
      display: false
    },
  }]
},
```

Per default the tooltip uses the xAxis label of a point which returns `undefined` when there's no xAxis label. You have to get the right label from your label array.

```
tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
      title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
        return sData.label[tooltipItem[0].index] // sData.label is your array with all data labels
      }
    }
  }
```

Complete code and example in [this JSBin](https://jsbin.com/wudusopowo/1/edit?html,js,output).

Comment: Thank you. From the looks of the example, it looks like exactly what I need.

Comment: No problem. Feel free to ask me if you can't apply my code to yours.